# In Galaxy, using the bracken tool, how do I get a Kmer distribution?

Tags: galaxy

As you can see in the image, the Kmer distribution field is empty: **"No options available"**

What am I missing?

Is there another tool I must use first to generate a Kmer distribution?

[image]

Comment: Try posting here instead: https://help.galaxyproject.org/